# scrapy how to get return value from another function

Tags: python, scrapy

how to return result to the call function?
I want my parse2 to return a value back to parse1, so parse1 can store it. 
right now I am just getting the url value, but not the return value from parse2

```
def parse1(self, response):
    for lst in response.css("tr.lst-rw"):
        url = lst.css('td[headers="lh_id"] > a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if url is not None:
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            res = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse2)

        yield{
            'response-date' : res    
        }

def parse2(self, response):
    yield{
        'response date': response.css('div#dnf::text').extract_first().strip()
    }
```

Comment: `parse2` is a generator.  I don't think this is correct: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects

Answer (score 0):

```
def parse1(self, response):
      s = self.parse2(response)
      #the rest of your code

def parse2(self, response):
      #your code
```